# Fixed header column width in gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I want to set header column width for grid view. I tried `HeaderStyle-Width="30px"`. But it is depending on Item columns. The column width is setting based on item value. But I want fixed width even if it has value or empty.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also give Header style-Width and ItemStyle Width.It is also possible to add a span and set the width .So the item width will remains a value whether it is empty or contains any value.I think a little changes to the gridview will makes you to achieve a solution to your problem

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Category"  HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                                    ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
     <HeaderTemplate>
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCategory" runat="server" ToolTip="Click here to sort by Category"
                                            CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="Category" Text="Category" />
                                    </HeaderTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                       <span style="width:50px"> <%#Eval("Category")%> </span>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="50px" ></HeaderStyle>
                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="50px"></ItemStyle>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
```

Nottable Changes are

```
<ItemTemplate>
     <span style="width:50px"> <%#Eval("Category")%> </span>
   </ItemTemplate>
  <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="50px" ></HeaderStyle>
   <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="50px"></ItemStyle>
```

Answer (score 1):

to make columns fixed length just add **HeaderStyle-Width="100px"** or whatever width you want or you can also include it in css file and apply it so tat u dnt have to make too many changes ..

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdvwnsaids" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                            Width="80%">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Product Name" HeaderStyle-Width="120px" ControlStyle-Font-Bold="true"
                                    ControlStyle-CssClass="MyText" `enter code here`DataField="BrandName">
                                    <ControlStyle CssClass="MyText" Font-Bold="True"></ControlStyle>
                                </asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Type" ControlStyle-Font-Bold="true" HeaderStyle-Width="80px"
                                    ControlStyle-CssClass="MyText" DataField="Type">
                                    <ControlStyle CssClass="MyText" Font-Bold="True"></ControlStyle>
                                </asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Composition" ControlStyle-Width="280px" ControlStyle-Font-Bold="true"
                                    ControlStyle-CssClass="MyText" DataField="Compositions">
                                    <ControlStyle CssClass="MyText" Font-Bold="True"></ControlStyle>
                                </asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Packing" HeaderStyle-Width="100px" ControlStyle-Font-Bold="true"
                                    ControlStyle-CssClass="MyText" DataField="Packings">
                                    <ControlStyle CssClass="MyText" Font-Bold="True"></ControlStyle>
                                </asp:BoundField>
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
```